# rename table in Redshift hangs indefinitely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, alter-table

I am trying to rename a larger table in Redshift and the process always hangs whenever I try to do so. I've also tried taking an alternate approach and altering the table to add a column instead and that hangs as well. This is happening on two of my larger tables in Redshift. I've checked for lock conflicts, etc. and nothing seems to be blocking the session. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just had one hang w/o any locks in `stvl_locks`, but I suspect something had been querying it in a long transaction, IDK.

Comment: if it's a large table is probably because is a long process time to execute the update you are doing. I'm not sure what happens under the hood when renaming a Redshift table but it might be that it creates a new one and drops the old one (just guessing but if it takes that long it might be the case). When I do such operations I monitor the disk space in Redshift if there is any substantial variation. In case of very heavy queries I also reach the "Disk Full exception"